# Commvault storage policy

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, backup, commvault

Hi I set up a storage policy last month and every seven days it was meant to back up sql, sql transaction logs and 3 windows servers (full system state), they are located on a remote site. The first time the policy ran everything backed up, however since then the sql and sql transaction logs have been backing up fine but the windows system state on the 3 other servers hasn't ran at all. When I look in jobs and schedule this only has the sql stuff in the schedule. I've configured other sites exactly the same but they all run fine, same server is (2003).

Any help would be greatly appreciated, hope what I've written makes sense :)

Comment: What did Commvault support say about this?

Comment: @EEAA Thanks for the quick reply, but still sitting with their support team

Comment: Well they should always be your first point of reference before coming here. Serverfault is not a replacement for a proper vendor support contract.

Comment: Yeh but just wondered if anyone else had come across this issue and if they'd managed to find a fix.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you're on a fairly recent version of CommVault/Simpana (9,10,11). If your CommVault environment is older than that you'll definitely need to reach out to CommVault for support. I'm also going to assume that you're using the "default" subclient for File System backups.

First thing I would do is open the Java Admin Console and check the backup history and associated schedules for the default subclient for the system in question.

*If you do not have access to the Java Admin Console or you're only using the Web Console you'll need to contact your backup administrator or reach out to CommVault support.*

Once you have the Java Admin console open you'll need to have the upper toolbar available. If it's not visible you can click the small ^ symbol in the upper right hand side of the console to expand the toolbar. The first button on the left should say "CommCell" once it's expanded.

- Click the CommCell button
- Double click on "Client Computers" in the new tab that's created
- Browse through the list until you find the system in question (CTRL+F works)
- Double click the system
- Double click the agent named **File System**
- Double click the backup set named **defaultBackupSet**
- Then finally right-click on the **default** subclient
- Select **Schedules** from the right-click menu

This will open a new tab in the Java Admin Console with details of the schedule policy assigned to the default File System subclient.

If there is no schedule policy listed then the schedule you created was not associated to the subclient and you'll need to re-associate it from the Schedule Policy properties of the schedule you defined initially.

Re-associating the schedule to the subclient can be done by selecting **CommCell**->**Policies**->**Schedule Policies**.

- Find the original policy you created
- Right click it and select **Edit**
- Select the Associations tab
- Select the **Edit** sub-tab
- Use the **Find dialog** to type the name of the system you're wanting
- Then expand the **+** icons until you've reached the **default** subclient
- Check the box for the **default** subclient
- Click OK
- Click OK again to apply the new association

If there is a schedule policy already defined for the **default** subclient, then you may close the new tab that was opened and go back to the **default**subclient.

- Right click the **default** subclient
- Select **Backup History** from the right click menu
- A new dialog will pop up with filters for the job history
- Ignore the options and select the **Advanced** button at the bottom of the dialog
- Another menu will open
- Check the box for **Include Aged Data**
- Select OK to proceed
- Then select OK at the prior menu

This will give you a full accounting of all backups that have run for the subclient which you can right-click on any non-green status backup jobs for **View Job Details** to get an accounting for why the job didn't complete successfully.

***Note:*** Prior to v11 sp7 (currently latest) only Completed and Completed w/ Error jobs would show up unless you selected the "Include Aged Data" option, now the box is checked by default and all job statuses are shown by default.

If you need additional assistance beyond basic troubleshooting please contact CommVault Support. Their published support number is Toll Free: +1 877-780-3077
Direct: +1 732-571-2160, or you can get current contact information from their website [CommVault Support](https://ma.commvault.com/Support)